# How to show only first, second, third Custom taxonomy conditionally

Tags: taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy names "colleges".

Here I have added A, B, C, D etc custom taxonomy.

And I want to show this taxonomy in single.php.

```
<?php 
    
$args = array('number' => '1',);
$terms = get_terms('colleges', $args );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
  echo  $term->name ;
}
?>
```

By using this code, I am able to show first item at particular div.

But How to show only B at another place.

Same C at somewhere else.

In short, I want to show one taxonomy conditionally.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You could just hardcode the name in those places... ✌ Or 2. You'll need to know the term ID or slug beforehand, then use functions like [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/) to get the term name. Or 3. If the terms are always in the order of "A, B, C, D", then for example you could `echo $terms[1]->name;` (after running `$terms = get_terms( ... )` again) to echo the "B" in another div/place.

Comment: have you tried using 'offset' in the arsg? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Comment: Contributors always write taxonomy instead of term word. You created custom taxonomy and added some terms - A,B,C,D. In your code you are showing just term name. But I think you want to show just one post from each term. Right?